# Is the spring singleton is only with one applicationcontext?

Tags: spring

I think singleton is only within one application context.

If having multiple application context for the same configuration files, the singleton will not be true anymore, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Why you would want to have two instances of an application context is unclear to me, though.